# How to control trains via code in railways scenario in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I open this new question directly linked to my previous question posted here:
[Avoid Exceptions after a train collision in Anylogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70684685/avoid-exceptions-after-a-train-collision-in-anylogic/70684949)

In a rail scenario, we use blocks to control and make run/stop trains. In the most simple scenarios, where trains and rail cars have no specific proprieties to embed, Trains and RailCars can be normal Agents.
In a TrainMoveTo block, we simply specify the acceleration and speed of the train and it moves consequently toward the specified target.

My scenario uses a RailSettings block to capture the event "On car hit car".
Its parameters are:

`RC car`  — the car
boolean frontside — the side of the car that hits another car (true if front side)
`RC other` — another car
`RailwayTrack track` — the track where this is happening
`RailwayNetwork railYard` — the rail network defining the railyard

if I call `car.something`, Anlylogic handles it as a simple Agent and I'm wondering, which function should I access to specify the very same information that I order via "TrainMoveTo" blocks? I tried with a simple `car.stop()` to make the train stop, but it didn't work.
The same question rises too in the very same case I want to create a specific Train and RailCar function and I want to control train parameters via code.

Can Anyone help me to understand this?
Thanks a lot!
Piero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic "trick" of agent-based modelling: Make the source block create not "Agent" agents but agents of your specified agent type:
[image]

Create agent types as needed, make sure they are flagged as Train or Rail car in the agent-type properties (see below) and make the sources create these. Then, it will be instances of that agent type flowing through your model and you can access their characteristics:
[image]

Best do all step-by-step tutorials in the AnyLogic help, they use this a lot (and it is a very core concept for everything) :)